# discord.py 2.0 app comands error handling in cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a bot model in **main**
Admin rights checkout in **classes/checkouts**
Two cogs - command and error handler in **cogs/dice**, **cogs/errors**

When an exception from **chekouts** appears, **error** do nothing. I only receive error message in console, but discord application does not response
So why is it happening?

main.py

```
import discord
import os

from classes.discordclient import DiscordClient
from classes.database import DatabaseInterface
from classes.checkouts import Checkouts


class Client(DiscordClient):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__synced = False
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='$',
            intents=discord.Intents.all(),)

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        if not self.__synced:
            await self.tree.sync()
            self.__synced = True

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        self.__database = DatabaseInterface('roleplay.db')
        self.__checkouts = Checkouts()

        for f in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                await self.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3])

    def get_database(self) -> DatabaseInterface:
        return self.__database

    def get_checkouts(self) -> Checkouts:
        return self.__checkouts


if __name__ == '__main__':

    bot = Client()
    token = open('token')
    bot.run(token.read(70))
```

classes/checkouts.py

```
import discord


class Checkouts:
    '''List of static utils methods, that checks user's unput'''

    @staticmethod
    def check_admin_rights(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        if interaction.guild.get_role(898307915348332614) not in interaction.user.roles:
            raise discord.app_commands.AppCommandError('User access denied')
```

cogs/errors.py

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


import random


class CommandErrorHandler(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener("on_app_command_error")
    async def get_app_command_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError):
        interaction.response.send_message('An error occured')


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(CommandErrorHandler(bot))
```

Comment: `on_app_command_error` doesn't exist *yet*. See the documentation about [regular events](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference) & [command events](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#event-reference). If you are interested about how to create your custom `on_app_command_error` event, please see [this cog on github](https://github.com/PaulMarisOUMary/Discord-Bot/blob/main/cogs/errors.py).